# std::vector::erase() (multithreaded) 'Assertion `px != 0' failed.'

Tags: c++, boost, stl, boost-asio, shared-ptr

Similar to [shared_ptr Assertion px != 0 failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541179/shared-ptr-assertion-px-0-failed)

I'm writing a game server that spawns a new thread to handle each user session. The main thread has a std::vector of UserSession shared pointers. Another thread periodically removes dead sessions from this vector but fails when performing std::vector::erase(). I can't find out what is wrong for the life of me.

The error is:

> Prototype2: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:653: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type
>   boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = UserSession;
>   typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type = UserSession*]:
>   Assertion `px != 0' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

The relevant code is:

```
void GameServer::start()
{
    int sessionid;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port_));
    boost::thread(&GameServer::session_monitor, this);

    for (;;)
    {   
        socket_shptr socket(new tcp::socket(io_service));
        acceptor.accept(*socket);
        sessionid = numsessions_++;
        UserSession* usession = new 
            UserSession(socket, sessionid, io_service);
        session_shptr session(usession);

        sessions_mutex_.lock();
        sessions_.push_back(session);
        sessions_mutex_.unlock();

        std::cout << "Starting session for client " <<
            get_client_ip(*socket) << std::endl;

        session->start();
    }   
}

void GameServer::session_monitor()
{
    for (;;)
    {   
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
        std::cout << "Removing dead user sessions" << std::endl;

        sessions_mutex_.lock();
        for (std::vector<session_shptr>::iterator it = sessions_.begin();
            it != sessions_.end(); ++it)
        {
            if ((*it)->is_dead())
            {
                std::cout << "Removing session: " << (*it)->id() <<
                    std::endl;

                sessions_.erase(it);
            }
        }
        sessions_mutex_.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Always use `make_shared`. Use a `std::lock_guard` instead of locking directly.

Comment: I also realise there a other things wrong with this code such as the concurrent use of std::cout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `erase` on an iterator invalidates it. You then attempt to continue to use it for iterating through the list. You need to use the return value of `erase` to continue iterating through the list.

```
    for (std::vector<session_shptr>::iterator it = sessions_.begin(); it != sessions_.end(); )
    {
        if ((*it)->is_dead())
        {
            std::cout << "Removing session: " << (*it)->id() <<
                std::endl;

            it = sessions_.erase(it);
        }
        else
          ++it;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way to remove things from a `std::vector` is to use the remove-erase idiom.  Looping over a container and manually removing elements is both annoying and is not going to be any more efficient, plus it is error prone because `erase` invalidates iterators on you.

`std::remove` and `std::remove_if` are already pretty slick implementations of that, and we can bundle them up with a call to `erase` such that the only code you write is the code that differs from one erasure to another.

Here are container-based versions of this idiom:

```
template<typename Container, typename Lambda>
Container&& remove_erase_if( Container&& c, Lambda&& test ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto it = std::remove_if( begin(c), end(c), std::forward<Lambda>(test) );
  c.erase(it, c.end());
  return std::forward<Container>(c);
}
template<typename Container, typename T>
Container&& remove_erase( Container&& c, T&& test ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto it = std::remove( begin(c), end(c), std::forward<T>(test) );
  c.erase(it, c.end());
  return std::forward<Container>(c);
}
```

Now your code reads like this:

```
sessions_mutex_.lock();
remove_erase_if( sessions_, []( session_shptr& ptr )->bool {
  if (ptr->is_dead()) {
    std::cout << "Removing session: " << ptr->id() << std::endl;
    ptr.reset(); // optional
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
sessions_mutex_.unlock();
```

or, shorter:

```
sessions_mutex_.lock();
remove_erase_if( sessions_, []( session_shptr& ptr ) {
  return ptr->is_dead();
});
sessions_mutex_.unlock();
```

As a final gotcha, note that if your destructor can be reentrant, you have to be extremely careful about the state of your `std::vector` -- if the destructor code causes the `vector` you are working on to be changed, you are in trouble.

If this is a concern, you can create a temporary vector to stuff the dead processes into:

```
std::vector<session_shptr> tmp;
sessions_mutex_.lock();
remove_erase_if( sessions_, []( session_shptr& ptr ) {
  if (!ptr->is_dead())
    return false;
  tmp.emplace_back( std::move(ptr) );
  return true;
});
sessions_mutex_.unlock();
tmp.clear();
```

which moves the destruction of sessions out of the lock (good!), and moves it out of code that is iterating over a nearly globally accessible `vector` (great!).

This does use a few C++11 constructs, but most can be stripped out if your compiler is pure C++03 without causing much damage.  (strip out `forward`s, replace `&&` with `&` on the `Container`, and replace `&&` with `const &` on the `Lambda` and `T`).

You do have to write up the lambda as a function or a function object or as a `bind` that the `erase_remove_if` calls.